# Setting up cURL much like POSTMAN

Tags: curl, vim, postman

I want to preface this question by saying: **Please feel free to redirect me completely if I'm going about it the wrong way.**

So I love working in the terminal and I wanted to setup cURL much like Postman with all various GET/POST requests you can make.

So I just make this super simple .md file:

GET Products

```
! curl http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/products
```

POST Products

```
! curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "@product.json" http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/products
```

I then coupled that with a VIM command:

```
map te yyq:p
```

What that basically does is copies the line the cursor is on, opens up the terminal history in vim and pastes that line into it. I don't know how to execute the command though (ie, `<Enter>` does not work).

How can I copy the line the cursor is on, open the terminal history and then press enter without closing the window so I can see the results?

Again... I might be doing this allllll wrong :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What that basically does is copies the line the cursor is on, opens up the terminal history in vim and pastes that line into it. I don't know how to execute the command though (ie, `<Enter>` does not work).

`<CR>` is the standard command to execute the current command line in the command-line window. See `:help cmdline-window`. You should investigate why it doesn't work for you.

As for your method, here is a more canonical one:

```
:.w !bash<CR>
```

that allows you to remove that Vim-specific `!` and thus make your Markdown file more portable:

```
## GET Products

    curl http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/foo

## POST Products

    curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "@product.json" http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/bar
```

[image: cap]

You could map it to something quicker if you want:

```
:nnoremap <key> :.w !bash<CR>
```

Answer (score 4):

Since Vim8.1, we could use `:terminal [options] [command]` to run command

```
nnoremap te yy:execute 'terminal '.@"<cr>
vnoremap te y:execute 'terminal '.@"<cr>
```

No `!` is required in front of command. You can also run command in visual-mode.

Use this to check if your Vim has it:

```
echo has('terminal')
```